# Redundant wording in a Java array and ArrayList declaration

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

A typical `ArrayList` declaration in Java is of the following type:

```
ArrayList<Object> name = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Similarly, for an array, we have:

```
Object[] name = new Object[size];
```

Now, we *certainly* can not have a declaration of the following type:

```
ArrayList<Object> name = new ArrayList<AnotherObject>();
```

The specifying of the type and the name of the same object two times has always seemed quite superfluous to me. The redundancy in the above declaration can be easily done away with something like this:

```
ArrayList<Object> name = new();
```

Is there any specific reason that I am missing out as to why it is done the way it is done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't. At least, not any more. Now you can do:

```
ArrayList<Object> name = new ArrayList<>();
```

You can't leave off the second `ArrayList` because it doesn't necessarily have to match the first. For example, you can do this:

```
List<Object> name = new ArrayList<>();
```

and you'll get an `ArrayList` but see it as a `List`.

Comment: You could also choose a subtype of the generic parameter I think, so OP was wrong about that or not? `ArrayList<Object> name = new ArrayList<SomeSubTypeOfObject>();`

Comment: Surprisingly, `ArrayList<SomeSubTypeOfObject>` is not a subtype of `ArrayList<Object>`. However, this would work, as long as you didn't want to insert anything into it: `ArrayList<? extends Object> name = new ArrayList<SomeSubTypeOfObject>();'

Answer (score 3):

From JDK7 onwards, type inference is present. You do not need to specify type on right hand side. Look here for an example: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/05/type-inference-from-java-7.html

You can write like this:

```
List<Object> values = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a dusty tome out there with regards to why it's done the way it is, but let's specifically look at the declaration of `ArrayList`.

To put a pin on it:  the ability to reduce the verbosity when newing up a generic wasn't in the language back when Java 6 was released.

[This is the grammar for declaring a `new` instance of a reference, back in Java 6.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/expressions.html#41147)

```
ClassInstanceCreationExpression:
   new TypeArguments (opt) ClassOrInterfaceType ( ArgumentList (opt) )
ClassBody (opt)
        Primary. new TypeArguments (opt) Identifier TypeArguments (opt) (
ArgumentList (opt) ) ClassBody (opt)

ArgumentList:
        Expression
        ArgumentList , Expression
```

The second production, or more specifically, the *TypeArguments* token is what is governing what we can put there.

[That changes in Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9), with the introduction of the diamond operator.

```
ClassInstanceCreationExpression:
    new TypeArguments (opt) TypeDeclSpecifier TypeArgumentsOrDiamond (opt)
                                                            ( ArgumentList (opt) ) ClassBody (opt)
    Primary . new TypeArguments (opt) Identifier TypeArgumentsOrDiamond (opt)
                                                            ( ArgumentList (opt) ) ClassBody (opt)

TypeArgumentsOrDiamond:
    TypeArguments
    <>

ArgumentList:
    Expression
    ArgumentList , Expression
```

So the verbosity no longer *needs* to be there, thanks to the *TypeArgumentsOrDiamond* token, but it's still supported by newer versions of Java regardless.

To your example, why we couldn't do something like this:

```
ArrayList<Object> name = new();
```

The main thing that springs to mind is, if you want to create an instance of a `List`, which is an interface and thus can't be instantiated, how would the `new()` method know which *kind* of list to pull back?  Would it always pull back an `ArrayList`?  A `LinkedList`?  Or one of your own types of lists?  How would Java know which one is correct without you telling it?

More directly, what should *this* produce...

```
List<Object> name = new();
```

...if we can choose between `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, or `SpecialUtilityList` which extends `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are familiar with other languages, such as C# or C++, that are able to infer the type of a variable; e.g.

```
var x = new MyObjectType();  // C#
```

or

```
auto x = someMethodThatReturnsSomething();  // C++
```

Java does its type inference "the wrong way around" if you are used to either of the above languages: you can omit the type parameter of a generic type on the right-hand side:

```
List<MyObjectType> = new ArrayList<>();
```

However, even though this may seem unintuitive at first, this is how type inference works and it is consistent and has advantages in other contexts; for example you can pass `Collections.emptyMap()` to a method that takes a `Map<Integer, MyObjectType>` and the compiler works it out without you having to specify the type of map you want `emptyMap` to return.

As for why you still have to specify the type on the LHS, that's the Java philosophy - you specify your desired *interface* on the LHS and your desired *concrete type* on the RHS.

Answer (score 0):

From Java 10 on, those redundant info can be omitted, we can choose to let the compiler infer the type by using `var`, e.g.

```
var objArray = new Object[10]; // (objArray instanceof Object[]) == true
var stringList = new ArrayList<String>(); // (stringList intanceof ArrayList) == true
```

To process `var`, the compiler looks at the so-called `initializer` (right hand side of the declaration), and uses its type for the variable. Details can be referred [JEP 286](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286).